# Avoid cached controlls being executed on postback

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-controls, outputcache

I've got a custom blog page and on the right side of the page, I have a "panel" that shows most popular blogs and another with people with most votes on their blogs in last week and three other such things. These panels are all sql heavy; they take a couple of seconds to load.

here's a rough overview of the layout: 
[image]

<sup>mockups created with [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Since they are not bound to change every so often, I've isolated them all into webcontrols (.ascx) and they all have an output cache :

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="7200" VaryByParam="*" VaryByCustom="CacheByModule" %>
```

And in `global.asax` I've got this to match my custom cache variable:

```
    public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
    {
    switch (custom.ToLower())
    {
        case "cachebymodule":
            Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Split('/')[0];
            break;
    }

            return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
    }
```

I'm essentially doing the same thing for different parts of my website, blogs, polls, surveys, quiz, etc..

When I run my page for the first time, all of them are being executed - which is expected.
On the next run - none of them are executed, which is also expected.

Now, this happens everytime- When I comment or reply on a blog, which is a post back event, and I am using an ajax update panel for comments section, all of my right hand side panels are being executed!

How do I know this? well, if I debug the application, the breakpoints in them are being hit for reply and delete (postback events). SQL Profiler shows just as much so that's twice the confirmation.

Is this the expected behaviour? The whole point of caching them is so they are never executed.. and yet ,with every reply and delete they are being executed. Only time they are not executed is on fresh page load (and within the cache time limit)

So, Why is it being executed on postbacks? 
and how can I avoid it, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is executed is because the URL + params are not the same for PageLoad / PostBack, therefore output caching does not work.
You could try and set the OutputCache `VaryByParam="None"`  in order to avoid reset when the URL changes.

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="7200" VaryByParam="None" VaryByCustom="CacheByModule" %>
```

Depending on what `CacheByModule` is doing this should work.

Comment: @LocustHorde You are very welcome, spend a lot of time with issues like that myself